# How to show a column value which has XML file in webbrowser - C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have table which stores entire XML file in a column. I want to show that column's stored value (ie. XML ) in web-browser using C#.

Please help/suggest some way to implement this. The trick is to retrieve the column and need to be displayed in webbrowser control.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Karthick

Comment: Ok i got an idea, while i retrieve the column that has XML values, i write and save to XML file. I navigate the webbrowser to point to that XML. Thats all :)

Comment: Could you possible add the name of the database you are using. This would make answering the question a lot easier.

Comment: Sorry its sql server, i found the solution, i retrieve the column, write to a xml file using StreamWriter, then navigate to that XML path for webbrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is the solution you decided to use:

1. Retrieve the column from SQL server
2. Write the XML to a file using StreamWriter
3. Navigate to that XML Path using the WebBrowser control.